# How to play H.264 video in a win32 window?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, video, ffmpeg, h.264

I came across a H.264 video which i would like to play in my c++ application. Could anyone suggest what could be the easiest way of doing it? Or What library can be used for the purpose.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

Windows API are [`DirectShow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375454%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`Media Foundation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (mind availability across Windows verions). You need a codec installed in Windows to be able to play the file, stock codec is only provided with Windows 7 editions. A choice of third party codecs is available.

Another option is to use a different framework such as [`ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org) which includes support for container formats and decoders.

Comment: Sir, does media foundation allow playback of .h264 file ?

Comment: `.MP4` file with `H.264` content inside - yes. Raw H.264 stream recorded into a file - not sure, unlikely.

Comment: sir, can there be a method which allows us to wrap raw h264 file in a mp4 container such that it can be played. And I mean to do it using c++ coding only.

Comment: You might want to check `ffmpeg` command line interface on how to remultiplex the file into `MP4` to make it suitable for recording, or to play it directly with `ffmpeg`.